# Save result of plsql script in Kettle variable

Tags: plsql, pentaho, kettle

What I want to do is storing the result of a PLSQL Script in a variable of a Kettle Transformation.

The script is located in a table input step and basically creates a select statement for me and puts it in a varchar variable of that PLSQL Script.

```
DECLARE

Statement VARCHAR(2000);

BEGIN

-- Here happens some stuff

Statement := 'select * from Foo';

END;
```

I just can´t figure out how I can map the variable Statement to one that exists in the Kettle Transformation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

After a couple days I was able to solve this.
What I haven´t realized when I wrote the question was that a mere PLSQL Script doesn´t return anything.
The solution is actually very simple:

1. Create a new Transformation in Spoon.
2. Create a PLSQL Function (which has a return value of course).
3. Inside the new Transformation create a step "Table Input" and there you can call the function like this:

   select myFunction('$someParameter') AS Statement FROM dual
4. If you want to provide some parameters for the function like I did make sure to check "replace variables in script" in the Table Input Step.
5. Connect that Step with a "Set Variables" Step ("Copy Rows to Result" works as well) and in my case I added the field Statement to the step with a new Variable that is valid in the parent job.